# How to call an ng-recaptcha callback from console Angular recaptcha?

Tags: javascript, angular, recaptcha

I was trying to solve an Invisible reCAPTCHA of the angular website (Implemented using ng-recaptcha).

It's ng-recaptcha (Invisible reCAPTCHA) and I am able to find the callback function using

```
___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].X.X.callback;
```

But when I try this in console or from selenium driver `script_execute()` function callback is not triggered.

[image]

I don't know a lot about angular method calls and hope you will suggest to me the correct way to the call callback function or a solution.

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Maybe it's just recaptch, doing its job?

Comment: But invisible reCaptcha always has a callback to trigger! Or can work without callback?

Comment: I just noticed that you're not actually calling the function: `grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].X.X.callback()` ( Note the `()` at the end)